# How to make exception in password locking via pam_tally2 for specific user?

Tags: linux, authentication, pam

I need to make an exception for a specific user, so that his failed logins are not counted by `pam_tally2`, and well, this is not a root account (I'd use `magic_root` then).

Is it doable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `pam_succeed_if` module in your stack to provide exceptions for some users. Check the `pam_succeed_if(8)` manpage for in-depth explanation of the syntax. An example would be:

```
auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so gid eq 2000
auth required                   pam_tally2.so deny=5 onerr=fail unlock_time=1200
```

That means, if the `pam_succeed_if` test returns successfully, i.e., for all users in the group whose GID is 2000, skip the following test (`pam_tally2`); if the test returns failure, ignore it and continue.

Several `pam_succeed_if` tests can be stacked up for fine-grained control.